How can I install Zen Browser from Builds on Linux and create a desktop shortcut for it?
I want to install Zen Browser from builds on my Linux (Kubuntu 24.04.1 LTS) system, but I’m not sure about the best way to do it. I’d love some help with the steps, especially for downloading, extracting, and setting it up so I can easily access it from my applications menu or desktop with all user account.

This will download the browser for the system (all user).

prerequisite: tar tool


Download the browser from Official Github Repo
Then extract the file and then move it into `/opt/ directory (your preference).
sudo tar xjf zen.linux-*.tar.bz2 -C /opt

x: Extracts files. j: Decompresses .tar.bz2 files. f: Specifies the archive file name.
Now create a desktop file to start the browser graphically:
sudo nano /usr/local/share/applications/zen.desktop


Copy and [aste the content below into the file:
 [Desktop Entry]
 Version=1.0
 Name=Zen Browser
 Comment=Experience tranquillity while browsing the web without people tracking you!
 GenericName=Web Browser
 Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
 Exec=zen
 Terminal=false
 X-MultipleArgs=false
 Type=Application
 Icon=/opt/zen/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
 Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
 MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
 StartupNotify=true
 Explanation of Key Fields:
 Exec=zen: Defines the command to execute Zen Browser.
 Icon: Points to the location of the Zen Browser icon.
 Categories: Makes it appear under the "Web Browser" category in the application menu.
 MimeType: Allows Zen Browser to handle common web content types.


Now you can find zen browser in your menu. (You can also start the browser from terminal by writing zen)


I think you have comments at the end of the desktop file which aren’t commented and make it fail.

On Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, to get @Jubyer's answer to work, I had to also make sure I had bzip2 installed, the .desktop file was valid, and zen was on my PATH before the application was picked up:

Download and extract zen (choose your version from the releases, or use .../download/twilight/zen.linux-specific.tar.bz2 for the latest prerelease)
wget -qO- https://github.com/zen-browser/desktop/releases/download/1.0.2-b.2/zen.linux-specific.tar.bz2 | sudo tar xj -C /opt


Make it available in PATH
sudo ln -s /opt/zen/zen /usr/bin/zen


Create the zen.desktop file
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/applications
sudo nano /usr/local/share/applications/zen.desktop

and put the following text into it:
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Zen Browser
Comment=Experience tranquillity while browsing the web without people tracking you!
GenericName=Web Browser
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
Exec=zen
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/zen/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupNotify=true



